# What board games have good quality versions available for play online for free?

Tags: online

What are some worthy online versions of board games?

They should be:

- Complete working versions
- On a site that is easily accessible (so no spam, lots of pop-ups or requires handing over excessive information to sign up)
- Is a true version of the original (same rules, look and feel, game play) so no poor quality clones
- Reasonably active community so there are enough players to have a game any time of day

---

EDIT:

To clarify they should be online games that replicate an existing board game. Not just any online board game.